# DevExpress DatabaseVersionMismatch Error when database has not yet been created

Tags: azure, devexpress, xaf

I am running a virtual machine instance of Windows 2012 server inside Azure.

I have installed SQL Server Express 2012 onto the computer

I have deployed my DevExpress xaf application using click once.

I edited the .exe.config file to have the following connection string

```
 <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Integrated Security=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;User Id=sa;Password=nottelling;Pooling=false;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mytest"/>
```

I used the ODBC Data source administrator to check I could connect to the SQL Server instance.

Yet I receive the following error when I try to run the application

```
The application cannot connect to the specified database, because the latter doesn't exist or its version is older than that of the application.
This error occurred  because the automatic database update was disabled when the application was started without debugging.
To avoid this error, you should either start the application under Visual Studio in debug mode, or modify the source code of the 'DatabaseVersionMismatch' event handler to enable automatic database update, or manually create a database using the 'DBUpdater' tool.
Anyway, refer to the 'Update Application and Database Versions' help topic at http://help.devexpress.com/#Xaf/CustomDocument2795 for more detailed information. If this doesn't help, please contact our Support Team at http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/ 
Inner exception:
```

Normally the database would create and self seed when I run the application

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out ( Thank you Paul Usher ) I was able to copy the DBUpdater exe file to the application directory in Azure  ( using cut and paste )

then I opened a dos prompt and ran the updater against the application config file.

this created the database and even ran my seeding method